# Get prefix from multiple wordpress sites with different databases with external script

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get the prefix of multiple databases of wordpress installations with different prefixes. But failing to do this and is getting me only the first table prefix for all files:

Folder structure (basic - has all required wordpress files):

```
home:
+---cpanel1
|   \---public_html
|       +---wp-load.php => $table_prefix = 'wp1_';
+---cpanel2
|   \---public_html
|       +---wp-load.php => $table_prefix = 'wp2_';
\---cpanel3
    \---public_html
        +---wp-load.php => $table_prefix = 'wp3_';
+---get_prefixes.php
```

Script get_prefixes.php (PHP):

```
$myfile = '/wp-load.php';
class execute_sql_code {
    public function __construct($myfile) {
        $this->main_work($myfile);
    }
    public $cpanels = array(
            'cpanel1',
            'cpanel2',
            'cpanel3'
    );
    public function main_work($myfile) {
        foreach ($this->cpanels as $cpanel) {
            $the_file = $cpanel.'/public_html'.$myfile;
            var_dump($the_file);
            require($the_file);
            global $wpdb;
            var_dump($wpdb->prefix);
        }
    }
}
new execute_sql_code($myfile);
```

`var_dump($the_file)` => OUTPUTS **CORRECTLY** every path.

`var_dump($wpdb->prefix)` => OUTPUTS **WRONG** `wp1_` for each iteration:

CURRENT OUTPUT:

> Iteration 1 => cpanel1/public_html/wp-load.php => `$wpdb->prefix = wp1_`
>
> Iteration 2 => cpanel2/public_html/wp-load.php => `$wpdb->prefix = wp1_`
>
> Iteration 3 => cpanel3/public_html/wp-load.php => `$wpdb->prefix = wp1_`

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

> Iteration 1 => cpanel1/public_html/wp-load.php => `$wpdb->prefix = wp1_`
>
> Iteration 2 => cpanel2/public_html/wp-load.php => `$wpdb->prefix = wp2_` // normal
>
> Iteration 3 => cpanel3/public_html/wp-load.php => `$wpdb->prefix = wp3_` // normal

Comment: I need this to load with wp-load.php not wp-config.php.If I load with wp-config.php and call `$table_prefix` works, but I don't want that because I need the `$wpdb` variable to play with.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you need to change the `array("username", "password", "DB1", "localhost")` etc, config to connect with the multiple DB's . also make sure your every folder's cpanel `wp-load.php` file load successfuly.

Using `new wpdb()` class will create a new object to play with current database or db functions.

For more info i would like to suggest [**wordpress stackexchange**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database)

```
$myfile = 'wp-load.php';

class execute_sql_code
{
    public function __construct($myfile)
    {
        $this->main_work($myfile);
    }

    public $cpanels = array(
       'cpanel1' => array("username", "password", "DB1", "localhost"),
       'cpanel2' => array("username", "password", "DB2", "localhost"),
       'cpanel3' => array("username", "password", "DB3", "localhost"),
    );


    public function main_work($myfile)
    {
        $i = 0;
        $cpanelKeys = array_keys($this->cpanels);
        foreach ($this->cpanels as $cpanel) {

            $path = $cpanelKeys[$i];
            $dbuser = ($cpanel[0]);
            $dbpassword = ($cpanel[1]);
            $dbname = ($cpanel[2]);
            $dbhost = ($cpanel[3]);

            $the_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $path . '/public_html/' . $myfile;
            include_once($the_file);

            $wpdb = new wpdb($dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname, $dbhost);
            $table_name = empty($wpdb->prefix) ? 'wp_' . "options" : $wpdb->prefix . "options";
            $sql = "SELECT option_value FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE option_name = 'siteurl';";
            $root_url = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
            var_dump($root_url);
            echo "<br>";
            unset($wpdb);
            $i++;
        }
    }
}

$obj = new execute_sql_code($myfile);
```

Comment: Tried also something like this just that I take the credentials dinamically via regex and file opening, but instantiating the class like that still did not work properly: $wpdb->prefix outputs empty string, despite the fact there are new credentials added every loop. And all the other elements on the object are null despite the fact it says is connected. So correctly back to new mysqli and php connection. + You cannot use the function from wordpress, like for example get_user_by($field, $username), it will output the same details for each cpanel like the above example is outputting the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that PHP cannot overwrite object `$wpdb` once its created in global namespace. Try to `unset($wpdb)` after `var_dump($wpdb->prefix)`:

```
public function main_work($myfile) {
    foreach ($this->cpanels as $cpanel) {
        $the_file = $cpanel.'/public_html'.$myfile;
        var_dump($the_file);
        require($the_file);
        global $wpdb;
        var_dump($wpdb->prefix);
        unset($wpdb);
        global $table_prefix;
        unset($table_prefix);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Probably some additional globals are created and you have to check `$GLOBALS` before and after `require($the_file);` to deduce which to unset. I would suggest trying `unset($table_prefix);` for example.

Comment: After `unset($wpdb)` I added again `var_dump($wpdb->prefix);` and it destroys the object, `$wpdb` become null, I think it has to do the the global variable scope.

Comment: @Adrian, I've udpated my answer. Try to `unset($table_prefix);` or analyze `$GLOBALS` to check for other objects.